# Multi-objective fixed-size subset optimization

Tags: python, r, mathematical-optimization

Here is my problem: I'd like to select k individuals out of n, so that the distances between the selected individuals is maximized, and their average values for a given variable is maximized too.
Ideally, I'd like to get a set of solutions corresponding to the 'pareto front'.
Computing a weighted-index could be an option, but I am not sure how to properly scale the two objective values.
Below is an example of the data I have, using R.

```
## create a n*m matrix, with samples as rows, variables as columns
## possible values are 0 and 1
n  = 100
m  = 300

set.seed(1L)
rows = lapply(1:n, function(x){
  p = runif(1)
  sample(0:1, m, replace = TRUE, prob = c(p, 1 - p))
})

## matrix samples*variables
mat = do.call(rbind, rows)

## Compute a distance matrix
D = as.matrix(dist(mat))

## Create random values 'S'
S = rnorm(n)

## idx = sample of individuals
idx = sample(1:n, 20)

## objective:
# select nsel among n maximizing S and maximizing D
# i.e. find the optimal subset idx that maximizes mean(S[idx]) and mean(D[idx, idx])
```

I had a look at different R packages like [mco](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mco/index.html), or [kofnGA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kofnGA/index.html). It doesn't look appropriate, but I may have missed something. Solutions in Python are welcome too.
Thanks.

Comment: One way would be to calculate min and max S and D. Then scale S and D accordingly such that they are between 0 and 1. Now you can easily use a weighted objective `wS + (1-w)D` by varying w.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. An index could be an option, but while I can easily determine min and max for S, determining the bounds of D would require two preliminary optimizations (to minimize/maximize D only). And then, to find the solutions corresponding to the pareto front, testing several values for w would be necessary. A more direct solution would be better. Thanks again!